# removing <br/> from GET request

Tags: vbscript, get, batch-file

I'm using a get request to get some page data but need to strip the break tags from the finished file.  Basically what I'm doing is taking the output of the get request and saving it to a file but it has hundereds of break tags in it I need removed.  I'm fine with running a batch or vb script after the file is saved to remove the tags but I'm not sure how on how to do that either.  So far the only solutions I have seen is to remove entire lines.

EDIT: This will be deployed to multiple Windows servers so I would like to keep the requirements as minimal as possible.  I.E. commands/software that Windows has by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you're au fait with Python, you could use Beautiful Soup to remove `<br />` elements in a fairly robust manner. See [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Removing%20elements) for how to remove elements from the tree.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I have misunderstood you could replace the break tags using the replace function in vbscript (assumed from the tag).  For example:

```
cleanedText = Replace(rawText,"<br/>",""))
```

More information on usage can be found here

http://www.w3schools.com/Vbscript/func_replace.asp

It is worth mention though that that function acts verbatim so you might have to run through a few times to get all common tag markup:

```
cleanedText = Replace(rawText,"<br/>","")) //no spaces
cleanedText = Replace(cleanedText,"<br />","")) // a space
cleanedText = Replace(cleanedText,"<br>","")) // unterminated
```

Comment: sorry I'm not all that familiar with writing vbscript.  How would I point this to the text file I want to use?

Comment: Apologies, I assumed vbscript as you had tagged the question with it.  What language / script are you using to perform the get request that pulls in the data containing the breaks?

Comment: I'm just using a cron job to make the http get request and write the output to a text file.  I was thinking of a vbs script that uses windows script host as opposed to vbscript in a page.

Comment: Are you using WGET (or similar) to make the get request?  If that is the case, as you need to edit the response, you will need to make the request in script that also handles the edits.  So for example your cron job could call a vbscript (or something else you are familar with) that performs the get and then does the response cleanup.